# -mouseMoved OSX does not get called in a sprite kit SKScene

Tags: macos, mouseevent, mousemove, sprite-kit

The following responder (defined in NSResponder) does not get called in an SKScene in OSX:

```
-(void) mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    DLog(@"TEST");
}
```

I have said the window to accept mouse moved events in the app delegate.

```
_window.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = YES;
```

Thank you in advance.

**SOLUTION:**

Add to the app delegate:

```
_window.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = YES;
[_window makeFirstResponder:self.skView.scene];
```

Answer (score 5):

Add to the app delegate:

```
_window.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = YES;
[_window makeFirstResponder:self.skView.scene];
```

Comment: The problem I see with this is that as soon as the first responder changes (aka, you click the window), this stops responding.

Comment: You can use `resignFirstResponder` to forbid the preemption.

Answer (score 2):

In swift

```
window.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true;
window.makeFirstResponder(self.skView.scene)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get at the window object and set it from the scene.

in Swift:

    `override func willMove(from view: SKView)
    {
        self.view!.window?.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
    }`

Comment: This is ”reaching out”. It’s assuming that the scene belongs to a view, and that the view is inside a window, and that the window can interact with a mouse. None of that is necessarily true, e.g. in a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers either make too many assumptions about what’s outside of your `SKScene`, or add a touch of unnecessary hackiness by messing with the responder chain.

`SKView` is a subclass of `UIView`. It inherits, therefore, the `viewDidMoveToWindow:` method. You can activate mouse-moved events for all your `SKView`s with a simple extension.

```
extension SKView {
    open override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        super.viewDidMoveToWindow()
        window?.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
    }
}
```