# SpriteKit MouseMoved Not Working

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, mouseevent

I know that this question has been asked before, but I think the answer may need updating since it doesn't currently work in SpriteKit using Xcode 8.3.3 for Mac OS. After reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704444/mousemoved-osx-does-not-get-called-in-a-sprite-kit-skscene), I realized that what could once be done in the AppDelegate should now be done in ViewController, but it's not working. Anyone have any suggestions as to why this isn't working? Here's what my various classes look like:

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
    GameScene *scene = (GameScene *)[SKScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"GameScene"];

    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene
    [self.skView presentScene:scene];

    self.skView.showsFPS = YES;
    self.skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    //added in hopes that mouse moved events would be captured
    [self.skView.window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [self.skView.window setInitialFirstResponder:self.skView];
}

@end
```

**GameScene.m**

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

}

-(void) mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"blah");
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}

@end
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the exactly same question a few weeks ago?

Comment: Yes. I completely forgot about that. Either way, no one had posted an answer. I'll remove the older question.

Comment: I can show you how you do it in Swift if you are interested.  I remember your old topic because I posted code in Swift and then removed it after realizing that you want it in Objective-C.  The concept is the same whether you write it in Objective-C or Swift, I think.

Comment: Yes, that would be great. I can do the translation from Swift to Objective-C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting your first responder to `skView`, you need to set it to `skView.scene` so that mouse responds to your scene instance, not your view instance.

Step 1: Move your window code to `viewDidAppear`

Step 2: change your first responder to the scene using `[self.skView.window makeFirstResponder:self.skView.scene];`

The reason why you need to do it in the `viewDidAppear` event is because `window` for `SKView` is `nil` during the `viewDidLoad` event.  Had you done this in Swift, `self.skView.window!.setsAcceptedMouseMovements = true` would have failed on you (Swift is a superior language, I would recommend using it)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
    GameScene *scene = (GameScene *)[SKScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"GameScene"];

    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene
    [self.skView presentScene:scene];

    self.skView.showsFPS = YES;
    self.skView.showsNodeCount = YES;


}
- (void) viewDidAppear {
    //added in hopes that mouse moved events would be captured
    [self.skView.window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [self.skView.window setInitialFirstResponder:self.skView];
    [self.skView.window makeFirstResponder:self.skView.scene];
}
@end
```

Comment: Something like this? `[self.skView.window makeFirstResponder:self.skView.scene];` It doesn't work. I wrote that inside of ViewController.m btw.

Comment: do not do your window code in the did load event, do it in the `viewDidAppear` event

Comment: Your window for your SKView is not the window of the root view controller at the time of load,  after the view appears, you know your window is on the root view controller because you can see it

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thanks.